# Rails - stray files are being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running my (rather-complex) rails app in development mode.  In my root directory, I see three files (zero-length) being created.  With names that make sense in the context of the application.  The names almost look like part of debug output.  I"m using Rails.logger for debug.

So - How can I find the creator of these files and remove it?

I've done the obvious searches, but who in the rails environment creates files in the root directory?

Thanks,
Oz

Comment: What are the file names? It will make it a lot easier to figure out...

Comment: There are always the same names,  but they won't help you much, since they involve the content of the application: "13,25,68,90}", "36," and "CD3".  The numbers are Color id's and the "CD3" is the name of a Marker.  The stray closing curly bracket is a lead, but I've done the obvious searches.